# Best way to store user changes to a public available Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in Firestore that is available for all my users. This way updates made by me to this database is instant updated for my users.

My challenge is that my users can edit some of the data in the database - user preferred values. These changes can of course not be written to the public database, but must either be written to a local SQLite-database on the phone or somehow written to each users private collection of documents in firestore.

A SQLite solution means that each time a document from Firestore is displayed, I need to read the local SQLite database to check for changes.

Using private collection of documents in Firestore means that I have to read two documents for each item that I want to display.

I struggle to find the "perfect" solution for this situation.

What is the best approach? Is there a solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet. Im thinking of a solution where I first downloads the public database to the phone and store it in a SQLdatabase and then update the users private collection. An other approach ive looked at is bulk write operations. I want to use the least possible read and write operations possible. A private collection of approx 100 documents for each user could be a lot of write operations if done wrong.

Comment: You can achieve this using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). Have you try it?

Comment: I cant see how Firestore Security Rules can fix this. Maybe I've been a little unclear regarding what I try to do. I'm currenly "reviewing" my database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach is Firestore Security Rules.

Any data for a user should go in a special document: `/users/userId`

Set up the firestore rules so that this document is only writable by the user with `ID === userId`.  You can make the document readable by all if you need or limit it to only the user who created it.

Comment: These security rules are used, but my problem is that I have a public document that is uptodate with values supplied by my and a private one with values supplied by the user. I need to find a way to update some of the values in the users private document when I update the same values in the public one.

Comment: I think you would need to use cloud functions for that.  see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated . For example, you could hook the firestore onUpdate event for `public/{userId}` and in that hook, copy the values you need over into `private{userId}`.